# static cells in tableview disappear when out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with static cells. If one of the cells are out of the view, the cells disappear and everything overlaps. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is the relevant table view code:

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return 4;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @meda I thought I didn't need that one since I'm using Static Cells?

Comment: actually you right , so you can comment out `numberOfRowsInSection` as well

Comment: you can post the cellforrowatindexpath???